# Hibernate 6, OneToOne association, Criteria request and Order condition

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, sql-order-by, criteria, one-to-one

I'm facing a problem with a criteria request while migrating a "spring boot 2.7 / hibernate 5" app to "Spring boot 3.1.1 / Hibernate  6.2.5".
The database is h2 2.1.214.

Here are my two entities with a one to one dependency.

*Root entity: Serveur*

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id_serveur", unique = true, nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long idServeur;

@Column(name = "type_serveur", length = 50)
private String typeServeur;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "co_acad")
private DvAcademie dvAcademie;
```

*Dependency entity: DvACademie*

```
@Id
@Column(name = "CO_ACAD", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 3)
private String coAcad;

@Column(name = "LB_ACAD", length = 100)
private String lbAcad;
```

When I make a simple request using criteria (without fetching or joining the DvAcademie table) with order on the Serveur table, everything works fine.

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Serveur> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Serveur.class);
Root<Serveur> root = criteriaQuery.from(Serveur.class);
criteriaQuery.select(root).distinct(true);
criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get("dvAcademie").get("coAcad"))));
List<Serveur> serveurList = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

```
Hibernate:
select distinct s1_0.id_serveur,s1_0.co_acad,s1_0.type_serveur
from public.serveur s1_0
order by s1_0.co_acad asc
```

**Problem:**
On the same request, if I fetch or join the DvAcademie table **AND** I want to add an order on the DvAcademie.lbAcad property, then, It doesn't work.

**Test1**
First, I tried the fetch method.

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Serveur> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Serveur.class);
Root<Serveur> root = criteriaQuery.from(Serveur.class);
root.fetch("dvAcademie", JoinType.LEFT);
criteriaQuery.select(root).distinct(true);
criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get("dvAcademie").get("lbAcad")));
List<Serveur> serveurList = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

I got this exception:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Order by expression "d2_0.lb_acad" must be in the result list in this case; SQL statement:
select distinct s1_0.id_serveur,d1_0.CO_ACAD,d1_0.LB_ACAD,s1_0.type_serveur
from public.serveur s1_0
left join public.DV_ACADEMIE d1_0 on d1_0.CO_ACAD=s1_0.co_acad
join public.DV_ACADEMIE d2_0 on d2_0.CO_ACAD=s1_0.co_acad
order by d2_0.LB_ACAD asc [90068-214]
```

Which is understandable because my order expression is not in the result.

**Test2**
Second, I also tried the join method.

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Serveur> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Serveur.class);
Root<Serveur> root = criteriaQuery.from(Serveur.class);
Join<Serveur, DvAcademie> acadJoin = root.join(DV_ACADEMIE, JoinType.LEFT);
criteriaQuery.select(root).distinct(true);
criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(acadJoin.get("lbAcad")));
List<Serveur> serveurList = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Order by expression "d1_0.lb_acad" must be in the result list in this case; SQL statement:
select distinct s1_0.id_serveur,s1_0.co_acad,s1_0.type_serveur
from public.serveur s1_0
left join public.DV_ACADEMIE d1_0 on d1_0.CO_ACAD=s1_0.co_acad
order by d1_0.LB_ACAD asc [90068-214]
```

Which is also understandable for the same reason.

So, my concern is how to make an "order by" work on the property of a join entity ?